# Timing of associated Legendre polynomials

Tags: numerics, polynomials, special-functions, timing

I encountered a strange issue with the associated Legendre polynomials implemented with LegendreP[l,m,z]. Quite simply, the time used for the numerical computation of those quantities depends on whether m is odd or even :)

For m even and z a real number, LegendreP[l,m,z] evaluate in a few milliseconds quite consistantly across a wide range of order l.
For m odd and z a real number, LegendreP[l,m,z] evaluate an order of magnitude slower and it gets worse with increasing order l.

I know that m odd means that LegendreP[l,m,z] involve the manipulation of square roots. If this is the reason, can anyone think of a workaround to get m odd evaluating as efficiently as m even ?

I use Mathematica 10.0.2 on Max OSX 10.10.4.

Thanks in advance.

```
 time0 = Table[Timing[LegendreP[l, 0, 2.]][[1]], {l, 1, 100}]; 
 time1 = Table[Timing[LegendreP[l, 1, 2.]][[1]], {l, 1, 100}]; 
 time2 = Table[Timing[LegendreP[l, 2, 2.]][[1]], {l, 1, 100}]; 
 time3 = Table[Timing[LegendreP[l, 3, 2.]][[1]], {l, 1, 100}];       
 Show[ListPlot[{time0, time1, time2, time3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: It may help if you post your code comparing the timings

Comment: something very trivial like : time0 = Table[Timing[LegendreP[l, 0, 2.]][[1]], {l, 1, 100}];
time1 = Table[Timing[LegendreP[l, 1, 2.]][[1]], {l, 1, 100}];
time2 = Table[Timing[LegendreP[l, 2, 2.]][[1]], {l, 1, 100}];
time3 = Table[Timing[LegendreP[l, 3, 2.]][[1]], {l, 1, 100}];
Show[ListPlot[{time0, time1, time2, time3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
  PlotRange -> All]

Comment: Sorry for the mess… I'm not used to nicely format code…

Comment: On my version 9 on windows, it takes no time at all to calculate any of those.

Comment: @coussin, You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: wxffles, I agree that in the grand scheme of things this example calculate fast. But I have a complicated code which call those LegendreP billions and billions of times and then, I can clearly see a performance difference between m even or odd. Are you saying that on Windows and with M9 there is absolutely no difference between m even or odd ?

Comment: I just noticed that those timing issues only occurs for an argument z>1…